# How to reset Ubuntu 18.04 to default theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, desktop-environments, reset

I had ubuntu 16.04 earlier with gnome environment and apple look alike theme with the help the help of tweak tool . Now I have upgraded to 18.04 . But I am experiencing problems with the apple theme, like some buttons not appear , icon names at the top bar not aligned correctly , etc. How to get default theme for 18.04

Comment: Apple theme looks a bit old now, you could try the seaching for "communitheme" in the Ubuntu store, install, logout and select the new theme from the "gear" icon and login. Alternatively, the more modern windows 10 look (which I prefer) can be download from https://b00merang.weebly.com/windows-10.html

Answer (score 27):

It may be easiest for you at this point to reset your theme and icons to the Ubuntu factory defaults with two command in the terminal:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

Open a terminal, copy and paste these two commands and your theme and icons will be reset to those of a freshly installed Ubuntu system.
To change to other installed themes later on, you can use Tweak Tool.

Comment: This fixed my problem, so thanks. Specifically  my desktop settings were dorked because it was an upgraded system that apparently gnome had been used in the past so desktop settings got established.

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: @raacer Only applicable for standard Ubuntu running with Gnome Shell (i.e., since 17.10)