# Restore Ubuntu to Default Appearance After Deleting Theme Files and Making Some Configuration Errors

Tags: themes

I made several mistakes in configuring my theme and want to revert to the default theme. Some things have already returned to normal, but there are still some errors, such as in folders, in some applications like 'system monitor,' and the wallpaper that automatically changes to a solid color when I open.

[image]

I have already tried the following commands

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

Comment: I have already tried the commands

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNOME, try resetting the themes and icons by entering these two commands into your terminal:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

From @vanadium's answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1054898/1746580

Comment: Did it not work for me